# I want to multiple select material dropdown in the table list

Tags: reactjs, dropdown

```js
const [age, setAge] = React.useState("");
const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

const handleChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent<typeof age>) => {
  this.setAge(event.target.value);
};

const handleClose = () => {
  setOpen(false);
};

const handleOpen = () => {
  setOpen(true);
};

<table id="customers">
  <tr>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Comments</th>
  </tr>
  {ViewChecklistItem.map((row) => (
    <tr key={row.TaskId}>
      <td>
        <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, minWidth: 120 }}>
          <InputLabel id="demo-controlled-open-select-label">Age</InputLabel>
          <Select
            labelId="demo-controlled-open-select-label"
            id="demo-controlled-open-select"
            open={open}
            onClose={handleClose}
            onOpen={handleOpen}
            value={age}
            label="Age"
            onChange={handleChange}
          >
            <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
          </Select>
        </FormControl>
      </td>
      <td>View comments</td>
    </tr>
  ))}
</table>
```

> Pls help me out
> Problem is when I select first dropdown will open four dropdown.
> here I attached my screenshot

[image]

> I want to select first dropdown open the only one dropdown. Not for
> others dropdown.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to StackOverflow. Nobody can tell you what's wrong with the code, we can't see. Please provide a [mre] demonstrating the problem. To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are mapping through an array to create multiple `<select>` components but all of those `<select>` have the same value for the attribute `open` so they open together and close together, that makes sense. they also have the same value for the attribute `value`.

so every `<select>` need to have its own `open` value and its own `value` age.

one solution is to declare your `open` and `age` useState hooks as arrays.

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState(() => {
return Array(ViewChecklistItem.length).fill(false); // this will initialize the open useState hook  based on the length of your ViewChecklistItem so open = [false,false,false,false] if you have for example 4 items in the list
});

const [age, setAge] = useState(() => {
return Array(ViewChecklistItem.length).fill(''); // age = ['','','','']
});
```

now lets update our `handleClose`, `handleClose` and `handleChange`:

```
const handleClose = (index: number) : void => { 
var openArray: boolean[] = [...open];
openArray[index] = false;
setOpen(openArray);
};

const handleOpen = (index: number) : void => { 
var openArray: boolean[] = [...open];
openArray[index] = true;
setOpen(openArray);
};

const handleChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent<typeof age>,index: number) => {
var ageArray: string[] = [...age];
ageArray[index] = (event.target.value);
setAge(ageArray);
};
```

finally in your jsx :

```
ViewChecklistItem.map((row,index) => ( // not that getting the index from the map function is very important here
<tr key={row.TaskId}>
<td>
        
<FormControl sx={{ m: 1, minWidth: 120 }}>
<InputLabel id="demo-controlled-open-select-label">Age</InputLabel>
<Select
  labelId="demo-controlled-open-select-label"
  id="demo-controlled-open-select"
  open={open[index]}
  onClose={()=>{handleClose(index)}}
  onOpen={()=>{handleOpen(index)}}
  value={age[index]}
  label="Age"
  onChange={(event: SelectChangeEvent<typeof age>)=>{handleChange(event, index)}}
>
  <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
</Select>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Now perfectly working.